# UIview Controller design should be in scroll view always to satisfy portrait and landscape design

Tags: ios, iphone, object

[image]I'm using AutoLayout class for designing it is working well in    portrait for all the IPHONE and IPAD  but when I'm changing orientation to    landscape some view goes out of the screen and sometimes giving error    Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you    don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint    or constraints and fix it.

please suggest me what to do

Comment: Hi, could you upload screenshot of your constraints?

Comment: @ruslan.musagitov I have added image please see it

Comment: Can you select container view (which holds those textfields and Register button) and do screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, You need to connect all subviews with constraints from top to bottom and Autolayout will do the rest for you.
[image]